# How to use RNGCryptoServiceProvider to get a random number greater than 256?

Tags: c#, random

How to get a random number greater than 256 using RNGCryptoServiceProvider ?

**Code:**

```
private static RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

byte[] randomNumber = new byte[1];

//Fill the array with a random value.   

rngCsp.GetBytes(randomNumber);
```

Comment: One byte = collection of 8 bits,

Maximum value of byte signed 127, unsigned 255

Answer (score 8):

Fill an array with 1 - 8 bytes, and use [BitConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) to extract an integer.

```
    static ulong RandomUInt64()
    {
        var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        var bytes = new byte[8];
        rng.GetBytes(bytes);
        return BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes);
    }
```

If you want to generate a random number within a specific range and also want to preserve the distribution, then you should generate a series of numbers and discard values not within the expected range (Monte Carlo method). I suspect this is the behavior you want if you're considering a secure cryptographic random number generator.

```
    static int Random(RandomNumberGenerator rng, int min, int max)
    {
        if (min > max) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(min));
        if (min == max) return min;

        var bytes = new byte[4];

        long diff = max - min;

        while (true)
        {
            rng.GetBytes(bytes);

            var rand = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes);
            var remainder = (1 + (long) uint.MaxValue) % diff;

            if (rand < max - remainder)
            {
                return (int) (min + (rand % diff));
            }
        }
    }
```

There's significant overhead when calling into the provider, so consider buffering calls to **GetBytes**. To generate numbers more quickly you can also select up to **log(range) / log(2) bits** from the random buffer, in addition to discarding samples that are out of range (to preserve the distribution).

```
public class RandomGenerator
{
    private readonly RandomNumberGenerator _rng;

    public RandomGenerator(RandomNumberGenerator rng)
    {
        _rng = rng;
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> Next(ulong range)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[8 * 512];
        var bits = (int) Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(range) / Math.Log(2));
        var mask = (ulong) ~(~0 << bits);

        while (true)
        {
            _rng.GetBytes(buffer);

            for (var i = 0; i < buffer.Length / 8; i += 8)
            {
                var num = BitConverter.ToUInt64(buffer, i);
                var n = num & mask;

                if (n <= range - 1)
                {
                    yield return (int) n;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> Next(int min, int max)
    {
        if (min > max) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(min));
        var range = (ulong) Math.Abs(max - min);
        return Next(range).Select(r => r + min);
    }
}
```

This will give you a useful API:

```
  var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
  var random = new RandomGenerator(rng);
  var randomValues = random.Next(-1000, 1000).Take(100).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Chris. Is it possible to use your approach to get a random number less than 100000?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Chris. But it takes too long to get a random number within the required range with this approach. E.g. It can take 30 min to 1 hour to get 5 numbers within the number range 1 - 10. I'm looking for an approach that is suitable for any number range and which can draw any number of random numbers within a given range. The random number generation should not ideally take longer than 10 min.

Comment: It seems the latest solution never picks the maximum value.

Comment: The range of the function is between min and max (exclusive); this is identical to the System.Random API. All you need to do to include max in the range is increase the max value by 1 when passing the max value argument.

Comment: You're welcome! Please remember to mark an answer as the solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I was told that the numbers given by this solution does not have equal probability and to check fairness of the numbers as done in following link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2                                  But not sure how to apply same to above solution.

Comment: In above example , why do we define buffer to be an array of length 4096?

Comment: The buffer size must be a multiple of 4; the selected size allows 1024 calls to be batched into a single call to RNGCryptoServiceProvider in the effort to avoid the overhead of calling into the provider.

Comment: I modified the answer to improve the speed of the algorithm. The buffer size should now be a multiple of 8. The speed can potentially be improved by not discarding an entire sample if the mask is less than the integer size (64-bits). For example, you may select up to floor(64 / bits) times from a sample.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason you need to use RNGCryptoServiceProvider for random number greater than 256?

as per mentioned by emert117, the maximum for byte is 255.

you may try just Random class if you need a random number.

```
Random _randomizer = New Random();
int randomNumber = _randomizer.Next(0,512);
```

Comment: You should not create a new Random object every time you need a random number. You get much better randomness by creating one single global Random object once. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @KlausGütter Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Apparently RNGCryptoServiceProvider is a better random number generator than System.Random class. http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter12/random.aspx

Comment: It's very dependent on your needs. System.Random is not thread-safe or cryptographically-secure, but for a vast majority of cases neither of those things matter. You can solve the thread-safety deficiency with synchronization.